# accessing views within a receiver

Tags: android

I have a parent application with this:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //hide view
    }
};
```

each activity has a reference to the parent application after casting getApplication. So in each activity I'm binding the receiver like this:

```
    registerReceiver(application.getBroadcastReceiver(), new IntentFilter(MyApplication.ACTION_RESPONSE));
```

How can I hide a view, which is used globally within a title bar, using calls within the listed onReceive method?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the current activity's context in application class, let say in CurrentActivity variable. Then use this context to hide the views of current activity.